# How to use ES6 Proxy in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I would like to try some things around Proxies, but i struggle to get the simplest form running.

I have the following code

```
const myObj = {
  x: 'Hello',
};

const p = new Proxy(myObj, {
  get: (target, key) => {
    return key in target ? target[key] + ' World!' : 'nope';
  },
});

console.log(p.x);
```

And i get the following error, but i have no clue why and how to solve it:

```
index.ts:7:28 - error TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string | number | symbol' can't be used to index type '{ x: string; }'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{ x: string; }'.

7     return key in target ? target[key] + ' World!' : 'nope';
                             ~~~~~~~~~~~

Found 1 error.
```

I think TS should be able to infer everything. What do i miss here?

Comment: TS *can* infer everything, you've asked it not to by setting noImplicitAny in your compiler options, so when you declare the parameter `target` you need to give it a type.

Comment: @Antony `noImplicitAny` doesn't make it infer anything any differently, and you don't need to give `target` a type because it is inferred regardless of `noImplicitAny`. `noImplicitAny` just makes TS error when the inferred type is `any`, which by the way, `target` isn't. It's `target[key]` that's `any`, not `target`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is because the `key` is defined as `PropertyKey`. Meaning it could be `string | number | symbol` which is different index signature than your object which only has one key `x`. It's not really error in types - TS cannot be statically sure that your object won't be called with something other than `x` and assumes broader range on possible `key` values. One solution to this could be assuring TypeScript that it indeed will be a `keyof myObj`, since you are already doing a runtime check yourself:

```
return key in target ? target[key as keyof typeof target] + ' World!' : 'nope';
```

Comment: You solutions works, but shouldn't be TS already sure with the `key in target` check that i only use a valid key?

Comment: This might be related to https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21732 , but unfortunately TypeScript cannot do that at this moment.

Answer (score 5):

Thx to @Rafal2228 for explaining the problem and suggesting a workaround. Just for completeness i want to post how i have fixed it now. (With a TypeGuard)

```
const hasKey = <T extends object>(obj: T, k: keyof any): k is keyof T =>
  k in obj;

const myObj = {
  x: 'Hello',
};

const p = new Proxy(myObj, {
  get: (target, key) => {
    return hasKey(target, key) ? target[key] + ' World!' : 'nope';
  },
});

console.log(p.x);
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm currently using

```
const someProxy = new Proxy(someObj, {
  get(target: typeof someObj, prop: keyof typeof someObj) {
    return target[prop];
  },
});
```

This will activate typecheck during writing the code.

But I'm tired of typing it again and again. Looking for a better solution now.

Answer (score 0):

You can explicitly specify the type of the `key` parameter:

```
const myObj = {
  x: 'Hello',
};

const p = new Proxy(myObj, {
  get: (target, key: keyof typeof myObj) => {
    return key in target ? target[key] + ' World!' : 'nope';
  },
});

console.log(p.x);
```

Answer (score -2):

What I discovered recently is that

> when you declare a local variable using the const keyword and initialize it with a literal value, TypeScript will infer a literal type for that variable (from https://mariusschulz.com/blog/literal-type-widening-in-typescript)

```
const numericLiteral = 42;     // Type 42
```

See https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/variable-declarations.html, https://mariusschulz.com/blog/literal-type-widening-in-typescript, https://blog.logrocket.com/const-assertions-are-the-killer-new-typescript-feature-b73451f35802/.

Also this may help you - https://medium.com/@SylvainPV/type-safety-in-javascript-using-es6-proxies-eee8fbbbd600.

You are not declaring literal constant, but something similar may be happening too. And I suggest to declare an interface to "support" the indexing.