# Maintaining Type safety Across Abstract Class instances

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I need help ensuring typesafety across the following generic abstract class, that uses a proxy:

**proxy.ts**

```
function authHandler<
  F extends Families,
  T extends controllerAbstract<F>
>(): any {
  return {
    get: function (target: T, prop: keyof T): any {
      return (...args: any[]) => {
        target.authorize((controllerClient: Client<F>) => {
            
          return target[prop](controllerClient, args);
        });
      };
    },
  };
}
```

**controllerAbstract.ts**

```
abstract class controllerAbstract<F extends Families> {
  controllerFamily: F;

  constructor(controllerFamily: F) {
    this.controllerFamily = controllerFamily;
    return new Proxy(this, authHandler<F, typeof this>());
  }

  abstract build_client(): Client<F>;
   
  authorize(consume_client: (client: Client<F>) => typeof this[keyof typeof this]) {
    consume_client(this.build_client());
  }
}
```

**concrete.ts**

```
const controllerFamilyName = 'FamilyA';
type ControllerFamliy = typeof controllerFamilyName;

class FamilyAController extends controllerAbstract<ControllerFamliy> {
  constructor() {
    super(controllerFamilyName);
}

  build_client(): Client<ControllerFamliy> {
    // build a client of type "FamilyA"
    const client = { id: 'A' } as Client<ControllerFamliy>;
    return client; 
  }

  // proxy "authorize" provides client object
  useClient(client: any, args: any[]) {
    // i want client to implicitly be of type "FamilyAClient_t" / Client<"FamilyA">
    // currently just using "any" as placeholder
  }
}
```

**types.ts**

```
type FamilyAClient_t = { id: 'A' };

type FamilyBClient_t = { id: 'B' };

interface ClientTable {
  FamilyA: FamilyAClient_t;
  FamilyB: FamilyBClient_t;
}

type Families = keyof ClientTable;

type Client<F extends Families> = ClientTable[F];
```

N.B where i say "concrete" class, i mean the contents of **concrete.ts**, i.e. that being a class extending the abstract class, with `FamilyAController` just being an example of this.

My goal is to make the `client` parameter of the `useClient` method in *FamilyAController* of **concrete.ts** to reflect the correct type based on the concrete class's `controllerFamilyName` const, such that i can call client.id, and i get the correct autocomplete of "A" if `controllerFamilyName == 'FamilyA'`, and "B" if `controllerFamilyName == 'FamilyB'`.

I have changed the explicit types in the proxy to try and get the types to be recognized as i need, based on the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59390026/how-to-use-es6-proxy-in-typescript). This is where i think the type safety breaks down in my implementation.

However, still this is erroneous, as:

- the proxy `target[prop](...)` line is giving an error of "this expression is not callable", as `target[prop]` is of type unknown. This is because not every prop of target is indeed callable, but some are, and i want to be able to restrict the type of target to this subset.
- my attempt at defining a return type for the `consume_client` function argument of the abstract class `authorize` method: `authorize(consume_client: (client: Client<F>) => typeof this[keyof typeof this])` . is throwing error. The intention is for it to return the type any method return type defined in concrete. For example, if another
  method existed on the concrete class, then the consume client return
  type should be able to automatically handle this new method return
  type. Hopefully you can see what my intention was here - to
  effectively "see through" the proxy layer to maintain the same return
  type that would exist based on *any* callable method of the concrete
  class.

Another trialed method was to define another abstract class containing just the abstract methods which are consistent with `target[props](controllerClient)`  signature, and use the `keyof` this class as the props type, to fix thefirst error. This was successful, but i am still unsure how to reach my final goal.

Essentially what i want is, in *concrete.ts* , to be able to write `useClient(client)` and the client type be implicitly `Client<ControllerFamily>` so i don't have to write `useClient(client: Client<ControllerFamily>)` for each method of each concrete class variation. Is this possible?

Hopefully this helps to clarify my objective with the code, and the current state of my progress with it.

Comment: Please [edit] the code so that it's a self-contained [mre] suitable for pasting into a standalone IDE.  Right now it looks like you've got undeclared types and values, and even some invalid syntax, so I'm faced with errors completely unrelated to your problem that I'd need to fix before even getting to the starting line here.  If you do make the changes to the question so that it's easy for others to get to work on it, and you want me to take another look, please mention @jcalz in a comment to notify me. Good luck!

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/w1A8Yw) meet your needs?  I'm not sure why you decided to annotate the type of `controllerFamilyName` explicitly, but if you let the compiler infer the type, everything works.  (Also note that I collapsed that into one file since multi-file code is harder to debug/copy/paste and unless you're asking about multiple files it is only distracting.  Also fixed spelling from Famliy to Family.  You might want to make these edits yourself). If this satisfies your needs I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: I very much appreciate the time you are spending to help me. I have been looking at it today and reached the same conclusion as you to remove the explicit typing. However, this just pushed my issue further down as the desired outcome is still not present. Ultimately, i want the `client` parameter of `useClient(client)` to *implicitly* be of type `FamilyAClient_t` if `controllerFamilyName == "FamilyA"`, and `FamilyBClient_t` if `controllerFamilyName == "FamilyB"`. I will update the post with my latest attempt at this and my thoughts, and incorporate suggested changes.

Comment: Okay, well, leave a comment mentioning @jcalz when you want me to look again (otherwise I'm likely to forget about this... last time I happened to check back again despite the lack of a comment, but you can't rely on that)

Comment: Hopefully the updated question is more reflective of my problem. Please see the penultimate paragraph for a general gist of what i want. @jcalz

Comment: This really feels like scope creep; we moved past one problem and hit a different one whose relation to the first is only because it's in your code.  I'm concerned that if I spend time and effort trying to resolve this one, you'll edit the question again with the next problem you run into.  Can you commit not to move the goal here?

Comment: So, [this](https://tsplay.dev/mp8lbm) is the closest I can get.  There is no such thing in TypeScript as class methods getting contextually typed parameters (you're calling this "implicitly").  You get type *checking*, but not contextual typing.  There have been various requests for such typing, and attempts to implement it (see [ms/TS#23911](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/23911)) but so far, at least, it's not part of the language.  Anyway, does this fully address your question? If so I can write up an answer explaining, if not, what am I missing? (Again, say @jcalz to ping me)

Comment: Yes, thank you very much for clarifying this and for your help. @jcalz

Comment: Okay I will write up an answer when I get a chance; it might not be until tomorrow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately TypeScript cannot currently give class method parameters "implicit" or ["contextual" types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#contextual-typing) inherited from superclasses.  You are required to manually [annotate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#parameter-type-annotations) all method parameters, and these can then be *checked* against the superclass, so you'll get an error if you do it wrong.  But you still have to do it manually.  This is definitely annoying.  There have been numerous feature requests to improve it (see [microsoft/TypeScript#23911](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/23911) for example), but none of these have made it into the language.  There always seems to be a problem with performance, or breaking real world code.  For now, the best you can do will be to manually annotate.

---

That being said, the closest I can get to what you want is to try to tell the compiler what `ControllerAbstract` actually does... which is that any added method must take two arguments, the first is of type `Client<F>` for the relevant [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type argument `F`.

I say "try" to tell because there's no perfect way to do this. No direct support exists to describe "all `string`s except for the known keys", so there's no way to say "any property on `ControllerAbstract<F>` except for `"controllerFamily"`, `"buildClient"`, and `"authorize"`".  There's a longstanding open feature request for this at [microsoft/TypeScript#17867](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17867) but who knows when or if it will be implemented.  For now there are only workarounds (see [How to define Typescript type as a dictionary of strings but with one numeric "id" property](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61431397/2887218) for a list of these).

One such workaround is to [intersect](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) the known part of the object with an [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures) for the "everything else" part. Like this:

```
abstract class _ControllerAbstract<F extends Families> {
  // ✂ snip ✂
}

type ControllerAbstract<F extends Families> = _ControllerAbstract<F> &
  { [k: string]: (client: Client<F>, args: any[]) => any }
```

But this is untrue; it implies that, say, the `buildClient` property will be *both* a method of type `() => Client<F>` *and* a method of type `(client: Client<F>, args: any[]) => any`.  And the compiler knows that's not true, so you can't just add the index signature to the class body directly.  Instead you need to do what I did above: rename the actual class body out of the way, and use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to convince the compiler that `ControllerAbstract` is a constructor that behaves as desired:

```
const ControllerAbstract = _ControllerAbstract as abstract new
  <F extends Families>(controllerFamily: F) => ControllerAbstract<F>;
```

---

Well, let's see if it works:

```
const controllerFamilyName = 'FamilyA';
type ControllerFamily = typeof controllerFamilyName;    
class FamilyAController extends ControllerAbstract<ControllerFamily> {
  constructor() {
    super(controllerFamilyName);
  }

  build_client() {
    return { id: "A" } as const;
  }

  useClient(client: Client<ControllerFamily>, args: any[]) { }

  useClientBad(client: Client<"FamilyB">, args: any[]) { }
  // Property 'useClientBad' of type '(client: FamilyBClient_t, args: any[]) => void' is
  // not assignable to 'string' index type '(client: FamilyAClient_t, args: any[]) => any'.(2411)
}
```

Looks good.  The `useClient()` method type checks, while the `useClientBad()` method does not, and the error there describes the problem, that `client` is `FamilyBClient_t` when it should be `FamilyAClient_t`.

---

So, there you go.  It's not perfect, but it's the closest I can get.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.8.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAYghgWwJYBsQEEDCKkQHbAD6wUAvFAN5RIAmAXFAOTqNQC+A3ALABQoksRKhAAhbLgLEylavSYjWnXkgIQATgDM4AY2jj8wACpwARimgVeUQcjToG8Wxn2Tg3HtcfCRDoWjE4BsTubLy8-NBegQDO0gDWECAA9hpQLkam5u7h4HqBBAA8MFAQAB7A+DSxUbjRAHzS6cZmEADaMAC62Ty8GgCueNrASEl4UHB9wAAWABJweDTmagVWsCXlldV+tQA0q4brFQuxmKPAakkoS+gm0ec6wEV1vHUAFACUDPMglKtqEMA+moxpYPNYoABzAEMfqDYajKCvYBwNRQ4AMQw7KBgC5gBgJZKpQyfcZ4H6g8Hg-6A4GIgB0DJREOiXzJrQ67zIDQplPByNRALpE2mSTUSAAXhBXq9tGcLld1OkGOknpzSNzVryqQCgWN+WjWjikmAOjK5ZcluksUzou93FrrGw7ZrwUowY69mC3aEer7THc1A8oNoUHBorFCKcCPLrrd7kMiodNjZULUNWDZdGLeooiAHN1rJmA30hqKzVmFWpcw5OTzrNMkNE6Znztmq34fuQWzGcx37dqaWM8BAAO5QAAKF1KICRU0b1sms3mi3URSxUdblZuAYeTze72dXrCYP98ZIJj6qBohBDEmAH2V+UeMDqBfGi9FEqlRb6CAgN6fBgZUAtIn1VLkoAiFJILnaJWgJaCoNSBtog5X53WDUZol-f9bwMWdGzpC8rwAu8PkPR1eB9XgixIDcezUbcz2kSNzS3ONAyGcZYlPTiSGHEdVkTMojiqFMYjebs22rWA1Qaei2yYvinm6CI0jY2MdwTYoROTGoIHqFiFPYrTnwaAAyXgqHghgAxUCEOiAvCCEfO8nmtVEWVJEB2Tk7z2GPGisJIKTK1zAA5RBoHIRhcxYdw1OMpZc2kJDMIrZKO0iv9uhDMMticLANPUJNjnUjL1CU3ckt7Jx00LYK1BLYAy1rF1sMgNRy03TKnGyiAKIC31rGIlBr2c+82ow6ldRkWgGAAInQBb2G49K7n7aiwT6aIIHSYC71cgwChq9s6o85lWR8tCqC26wdr2p8RDgGgDoMI7CgW3MRAWuoLq875fJkH1rAAelBidcXUUAmAe9JnpoVhENyJg3pc8TRHSYh-quoH1SgAA3JJaFYRtVnBqA8CSEh8qQCE8EyaAWqYOy8AhUmFjKSCUcYNH0QxrAn2x8ZPNxtD8e+Rg6VeAAmAAWABGBX3iowKeCAA)